# Uninstalling unwanted applications

Tags: uninstall, installed-programs

In windows, I can see all the programs installed in control panel -> programs and then can uninstall unwanted programs.
But in ubuntu 11.04, how can I see such list of installed programs and then uninstall them ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the Software Center and click on **Installed** it will show a menu tree of installed applications.

[image]

Open each menu tree and you can see the program installed, when you click on them they will highlight and tow radio buttons will be visible: **More Info** and **Remove**

[image]

Click **Remove** and enter your password and it will remove the app.

Click on **More Info** to get a description of the app. You can then use the back arrow at the upper left to get back to the **Installed** tab and the previous menu will will still be open and the last selected app still highlighted.